# Sri Lalithopakhyanam telugu version

Tags: scripture, brahmanda-purana, lalita, telugu

I want to learn and do parayana of Sri Lalithopakhyanam (contained in Brahmanda Purana). I am looking for any good Telugu resources of the original Sanskrit text and translations to Telugu. I have searched online and in near-by stores, but couldn't find any good ones.

Please can you kindly share any info you may have.

Best Regards